# Why is Selenium logging ERROR messages on Chrome browser startup?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Everytime I launch tests with selenium, something like this appears in the console:

```
[5124:4344:1128/184821.088:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(226)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[5124:4344:1128/184821.145:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(229)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[5124:4344:1128/184821.195:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(232)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[5124:4344:1128/184821.289:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
```

How can I disable it?

Comment: Regular Chrome logs that too if you tell it to log to a console. It's not a Selenium thing.

Answer (score 0):

These error messages...

```
[5124:4344:1128/184821.088:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(226)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[5124:4344:1128/184821.145:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(229)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
```

...are the result of some *parametrized tests being flaky due to a timeout in recording expensive metrics on startup*.

As per the discussion [Parametrized tests are flaky due to a timeout in recording expensive metrics on startup](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1216328) `isherman@chromium.org` mentions either of the calls in [chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/metrics/chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc;l=199;drc=a4f34441d6ba2bfec6a21e2ff88afaf2d18eb9db) are flaky:

- [bluetooth_utility::ReportBluetoothAvailability()](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/metrics/chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc;l=227;drc=a4f34441d6ba2bfec6a21e2ff88afaf2d18eb9db)
- [shell_integration::GetDefaultBrowser()](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/metrics/chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc;l=231;drc=a4f34441d6ba2bfec6a21e2ff88afaf2d18eb9db)

`asvitkine@chromium.org` in his [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/df6c9e0a0802cf1e5620c5c5c711dd5231da7cc5) mentioned:

> Don't log histogram `DefaultBrowser.State` on Linux. The code to query
> the default browser state sometimes hangs Chrome start up on browser
> tests bots, causing flakiness. Disable the relevant code on Linux
> until a solution can be found. Also, revise some instrumentation
> messages to be more concise and more clear about when the bug in
> question might happen. Once this lands, we should be able to see if
> any more tests are affected by this or whether the bug can be closed
> and diagnostic logs can be removed.

This fix should address the issue in the upcoming releases once the *flaky tests* are addressed.

However, these log messages doesn't effects your tests and you can live with those.

Comment: For future reference: according to [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/testing_guide/flaky_tests.html), "[A flaky test] is a test that sometimes fails, but if you retry it enough times, it passes, eventually."
By the way, it is 2022 and the same issue arises with the current version of Selenium.